# Clojure: just return the value

Tags: clojure

Is there any Clojure built-in function that just returns the value being passed to it? The equivalent of

```
(defn just-val [x] x)
```

?

Comment: It's an interesting question. Is this for parameter checking?

Comment: i need to either return a value untouched or to apply a function to it, so i can pass the function to apply that's either a function doing something or (identity), as learned by ollb answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there is the identity function:
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/identity

```
user=> (identity 4)
4
```